# Crash with PFQueryTableViewController and UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchbar

The crash msg

> UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.29.5/UITableView.m:6547
>   2015-12-08 16:29:01.851 EventAppTest[51390:3508575] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier EventCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

But it fetches all objects so the cell is there why it crashes only after tapping the search bar?

What seems the problem ?

```
    import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class EventListVC: PFQueryTableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var searchString = ""
    var searchInProgress = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        searchBar.delegate = self

    }

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Event")

        if searchInProgress {
            query.whereKey("eventTitle", containsString: searchString)
        }
        if self.objects!.count == 0 {

            query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
        }

        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        return query

    }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        // Configure the cell


        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? EventTableCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = EventTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "EventCell")
        }

        cell!.titleLabel.text = object?.objectForKey("eventTitle") as? String



        return cell

    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchString = searchText
        searchInProgress = true
        self.loadObjects()
        searchInProgress = false
    }


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchString = searchBar.text!
        self.loadObjects()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchString = ""
        self.loadObjects()
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: Have you made a custom nib file for your cell?

Comment: no I did not , I only made the cell in the storyboard with PFTableViewCell

Comment: Ok then have you specified the cell identifier in your storyboard?

Comment: I think the issue in >> query.whereKey(col name here ?, containsString: searchString)  >>> is this right?

Comment: According to the error you posted above, it says that its not able to find a cell with identifier as "EventCell"

Comment: yes no crash at all objects are fully there but the crashes appears after tapping search bar

Comment: If thats the case, then i think loadObjects() will be having some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it :)

from this

```
 var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? EventTableCell
```

to this

```
 var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as? EventTableCell
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you are getting, I think you have missed out specifying the Cell Identifier.
 You can find this in the properties window on the right side of Xcode
Try changing the "Identifier" from this image to the next image's value.
[image: Try changing the "Identifier"]

Here you will specify the identifier 
[image: To This]

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but it is there in the storyboard otherwise the will crash before it start

Comment: Hmm, can you post loadObjects() function?

Comment: The problem might be in the search bar but this error comes when the compiler cannot load the cell (meaning some error with the cell)

Comment: exactly, I guess that it wants to gets the cells that match the entered search text but the cell isn't declared for that !

Comment: Ok so if you want to perform a search functionality, try this out. https://github.com/marmikshah/Auto-Complete
its a simple project with working search